# Convolution of two symbolic arrays on Matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution, symbolic-math

I have two arrays:

```
p1=[sym(1) sym(2)]
p2=[sym(3) sym(4)]
```

I want to do the convolution of those two lists using `conv` function.

Matlab outputs the following:

> Error using conv2
>
> Invalid data type. First and second arguments must be numeric or logical.
>
> Error in conv (line 43)
>
> c = conv2(a(:),b(:),shape);

Can anyone help me how to deal with that?

Comment: You can use a simple `for` loop to do the multiplication yourself. Flip one of the arrays, then multiply each element with each other element. Besides, you mention `conv()`, but the errors use `conv2()`.

Comment: @Adriaan I want to do the convolutions for very large arrays. This was just an illustration. So the `for` loop is not a good solution.Yes I don't know why the error contains `conv2`!

Comment: How would a `for` loop not be a good solution for very large arrays? As far as I know, `conv` contains loops under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1: i have not symbolic math toolbox so i demonstrated a matrix-wise operation on numeric values to calculate conv, i think this should do the trick on symbolic values either.**

the conv function just accept numeric values.
there is a way to calculate conv matrix-wise
i demonstrate it with an example:
assume u and v are as follows :

```
u =
     1     2     1     3
v =
     2     7     1

>> conv(u,v)
ans =
     2    11    17    15    22     3
```

instead we could first calculate u'*v, then do some rearranging and summing to calculate conv:
so first :

```
>> c=u'*v
c=
     2     7     1
     4    14     2
     2     7     1
     6    21     3
```

then we do some rearranging:

```
>> d=[c;zeros(3,3)]
d =
     2     7     1
     4    14     2
     2     7     1
     6    21     3
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
>>e= reshape(d(1:end-3),[6,3])
e=  
     2     0     0
     4     7     0
     2    14     1
     6     7     2
     0    21     1
     0     0     3
```

and finally adding values together :

```
>> sum(e,2)
ans =
     2
    11
    17
    15
    22
     3
```

you can write your own code to use "v size" to do it(add (numel(v)*numel(v)) zeros to end of u'*v and so on.)